# List issues in Github that don't have a PR

Tags: github, pull-request, issue-tracking

I use `github.com/issues/assigned` to find issues that are assigned to me, to work on. But many of them I have already opened a PR for. Is there a way to filter out those that already have a PR linked to them?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking about the website, or about the GitHub API?

Comment: Good question: The website.

Answer (score 1):

sticking with the website GUI, it may be helpful to [sort by lack of activity](https://help.github.com/articles/sorting-search-results/#sort-by-interactions), which will put issues with fewer reactions and comments up top:

```
assignee:stevage is:issue is:open sort:interactions-asc
```

e.g.:

https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=assignee%3Astevage+is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Ainteractions-asc

but this does not provide what you asked for.

to retrieve a list of all open issues assigned to you and then remove those that have been mentioned by a comment on a pull request submitted by you seems non-trivial, but is probably possible with some scripting against the [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/working-with-comments/#pull-request-comments).

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice thought. In my case it doesn't seem to help much, as both issues that are recently raised, or recently worked on, get grouped together. (And vice versa).